# Twilio with Supabase & Flutter unmarshal number into Go struct field SmsStatus.status

Tags: flutter, twilio, supabase

I am using new package with documentation and implementation but every time when i try to send the otp to number through console or through function provided it returns the following error

```
'''Sending OTP failed: Error sending sms otp: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field SmsStatus.status of type string'''
```

just a simple supabase call to signin with phone number and then send otp to specific number

```
 Future<void> signInUser(String phonenum) async {
                                           response   = await supabaseClient.auth.signIn(
                                       phone: phonenum,
                                       options: AuthOptions(redirectTo: 'https://vmlkpbfoohvcmnzgkkpr.supabase.co'),
                                
                                           );
if (response.error != null) {
  // Error

  print(response.data.toString());
  print('Error: ${response.error?.message}');
} else {
  // Success
  final session = response.data;
} }'''
```

Comment: Can you share the code you are using?

Comment: Stuck at the same issue. tried making an http request as well as tried using the library but still got the same error

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I don't know what solved it but here's what I did:

- from console.twilio under develop->messaging->'send an sms' I sent an sms to test
- then I made sure 'SID' and 'Auth Token' on Twilio is correctly copied under Supabase Dashboard->Authentication->Users->Settings->Phone Auth